# How store feature changes with geotools?

Tags: geotools, versioning

I stored a vector layer in postgis and I can add, remove or update featues successfully. Now I want to store feature change log(This means if a feature property changed, we can access new and old properties). Or we want to have feature versioning with geotools. I want to know Geotools has any library for implement versioning? In theory, whats the best way to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing directly built into [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) but you could use [GeoGig](http://geogig.org/) which is built using [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) and designed to plugin to [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org).

Alternatively, you could use some sort of [PostgreSQL audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger) that stores changes to features in the database in a table so that you can rollback to a specific point in time by executing the commands stored in the table. GeoTools is unaffected by this approach. I would go for this approach as it covers all changes made to the table no matter which client is responsible for the change.